# playing video in unity3d for Android with Mobile Movie Texture

Tags: android, video, unity-game-engine

Salaam,
I use vuforia sdk version 5 to design AR apps in unity5.1 . I want to play a video on ImageTarget, so I use Mobile Movie Texture ([link](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2449)), But when I aim device camera at image I see a green plane instead of video. Everything was OK when I use vuforia sdk 2.3 with unity 4.
here a screenshot of my mobile when I run my AR app. I did't print imageTarget, i show it in my laptop screen.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delete the video and try to reimport it again. Same thing happened to me when i migrated a Unity 4 project to 5. I just reimported the videos and they work again normally.